# Show that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]= \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]= \emptyset$

My attempt:

Take a random $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]$. Then $x > 0$ and for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \leq \frac{1}{N}$. But then it's obvious that $x$ cannot exist, so $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}] \subset \emptyset$

It's obvious that $\emptyset \subset \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]$, since the empty set is a subset of every set.

Together, $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]= \emptyset$.

Comment: you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of what you're doing is correct, but it could be worded better.  In particular, the part where you say it's obvious that $x$ can't exist is kinda the whole point, so I'd spell that out instead of just saying it's obvious.

For a given positive $x$ I would say explicitly how to choose $n$ such that $x \notin (0, \frac{1}{n}]$, which then proves that $x$ is not in that intersection.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's because of the Archimedean property. I should have written that... because there exist N such that $x>\frac{1}{N}$, but that means we could pick an N large enough so that x only exist as a limit value, but x cannot be 0 either because of the design of the interval.